# Chromium inside docker image on Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-chrome-headless, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to have a docker container running on google cloud run, which is containing a simple nodejs app and google chromium headless to create a PDF from HTML source.
Unfortunately, Google Cloud Run seems to have issues with thatever solution I try.

My Docker image(s) run perfectly locally and on other providers (i.E. Azure), but GCP just does not work.

What I try:

Basically building any docker image, installing node, npm, chromium,
then running chromium --headless in the background.
Then running the node app.
The Node app is simply trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:9222 => that doesn't work on GCP, but anywhere else.

I tried with the official node images of docker hub
I tried with an alpine image
I tried with a debian image
All of these run fine locally, but not on google cloud run.

Here's my latest test with a debian image:

```
FROM debian:latest


RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        nodejs yarn npm chromium \
        && apt-get clean \
        && apt-get autoclean
RUN adduser --home /home/node --disabled-password --gecos "" node \
        && mkdir /home/node/app \
        && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN npm cache clean -f
RUN npm i -g n
RUN n stable
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node/app
ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium \
        CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/

ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}


COPY --chown=node . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000

EXPOSE ${PORT}

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "/home/node/app/docker-inside-start.sh" ]
```

Entrypoint sh is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec $CHROME_BIN --headless --use-gl=swiftshader \
        --disable-software-rasterizer --disable-dev-shm-usage --remote-debugging-port=9222 \
        --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0 --no-sandbox --disable-gpu \
        --no-first-run --no-crash-upload --no-pings --no-wifi &
node .
```

My Node code looks like this. Nothing fancy..
APP_CONFIG_CHROME_HOST is set to localhost or 127.0.0.1 - nothing works

```
import * as htmlPdf from 'html-pdf-chrome';
// ...
private createPdf(html: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const options: htmlPdf.CreateOptions = {
          host: process.env.APP_CONFIG_CHROME_HOST,
          port: 9222, // port Chrome is listening on
        };
        htmlPdf.create(html, options)
          .then((pdf) => resolve(pdf.toBase64()))
          .catch(e => reject(e));
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

Finally the errors/output I see :

```
2020-09-12 15:26:02.786 MESZ[0912/132602.785920:WARNING:discardable_shared_memory_manager.cc(194)] Less than 64MB of free space in temporary directory for shared memory files: 0

2020-09-12 15:26:38.827 MESZ[0912/132638.826713:ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(201)] Could not bind NETLINK socket: Permission denied (13)

2020-09-12 15:26:38.828 MESZ[0912/132638.828564:ERROR:file_path_watcher_linux.cc(71)] Failed to read /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
...
2020-09-12 15:28:28.364 MESZ[2020-09-12T13:28:26.764Z] [ERROR] <mail.service.js> Error: socket hang up
```

Any ideas anyone?

Note: the errors when using for example an alpine image are different. Googling points to hints that gcp has a general issue with some other part there. To be specific, in gvisor:
https://github.com/google/gvisor/issues/1739#issuecomment-673861090
In case you want to experience that, heres a docker image doing the same like the above one but on alpine:
chrome doesn't run there and exits with complaining about missing membarrier syscall

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG BUILD_DATE
ARG VCS_REF

LABEL org.label-schema.build-date=$BUILD_DATE \
        org.label-schema.description="Chrome running in headless mode in a tiny Alpine image" \
        org.label-schema.name="alpine-chrome" \
        org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0.0-rc1" \
        org.label-schema.usage="https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome/blob/master/README.md" \
        org.label-schema.vcs-url="https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome" \
        org.label-schema.vcs-ref=$VCS_REF \
        org.label-schema.vendor="Zenika" \
        org.label-schema.version="latest"

# Installs latest Chromium package.
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" > /etc/apk/repositories \
        && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
        && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
        && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
        && apk upgrade -U -a \
        && apk add --no-cache \
        libstdc++ \
        chromium \
        harfbuzz \
        nss \
        freetype \
        ttf-freefont \
        wqy-zenhei \
        tini make gcc g++ python git nodejs nodejs-npm yarn \
        && rm -rf /var/cache/* /var/lib/apt/lists/* /usr/share/man /tmp/*

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app \
        && adduser -D node \
        && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node/app

ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser \
        CHROME_PATH=/usr/lib/chromium/


# set ENV to development if NOT given in command line
ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

COPY --chown=node package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node . .

RUN npm run build

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000

EXPOSE ${PORT}
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "/home/node/app/docker-inside-start.sh" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running chrome inside Cloud Run to transform webpages to PDF (and ten to SVG). Find my repo [here](https://github.com/as-a-service/html-to-svg)

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-slim

    # Add contrib packages for ms fonts
RUN echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    # Adds required libs for Headless Chrome
    apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
    libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
    libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
    ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget \
    # fonts
    ttf-mscorefonts-installer fontconfig && \
    fc-cache -f

# Start the app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And here is the relevanr part of my Node.js code using `"puppeteer": "^3.0.4"`:

```
    if(!browser) {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: ['--no-sandbox']
        });
    }
    if(!page) {
        page = await browser.newPage();
    }

    // https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions
    await page.emulateMedia('screen');
    let printParams = {
        path: inputPDFFilename,
        width,
        printBackground: true
    };
    if(height) {
        printParams.height = height;
    }
    await page.pdf(printParams);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sterem, that was very promising. I re-created the same and just executed it with success locally. However. After deploying to google cloud run, I am facing this error:
```2020-09-14 08:28:58.260 MESZ[2020-09-14T06:28:58.060Z] [ERROR] <mail.service.js> TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to the browser! Only Chrome at revision r800071 is guaranteed to work.````
Found this: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4796 but I don't see a solution as of now.. GCP is very disappointing so far. Not sure why I'm going through this anymore.

Comment: Just to follow up. I tried with puppeteer 5.x. After downgrading to 3.x like you've advised. I get the same for a different version, also after roughly 30 seconds: `2020-09-14 09:06:47.264 MESZ[2020-09-14T07:06:45.763Z] [ERROR] <mail.service.js> TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to the browser! Only Chrome at revision r756035 is guaranteed to work.` I guess I will move our app to AWS or keep running it on azure. GCP just seems to be incompatible with many things.
- all phantomjs versions
- chrome headless as a service
- chrome direct execution via puppeteer

Comment: From the build log:
`Step #0 - "Build": Chromium (756035) downloaded to /home/node/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-756035`

Comment: I'm updating this and accepting your solution, as I tried your repository, everything works there. Unfortunately my application (a Loopback 4 Project) with the exact same libraries and exact same code doesn't run. So I might be running into a thing which is out of my scope.... I removed the logic from said api and created a microservice just for this task, that runs without issues.
very strange. That being said, the initial finding still is true for me: the application (loopback4 with that PDF generation runs everywhere, but on GCP.). Cheers

Comment: "GCP" have many other places to run containers than Cloud Run, please take a look at Kubernetes Engine or Compute Engine. Also, avoid commenting you will "move your app to AWS". This is not relevant to this StackOverflow answer.