# Failed to launch the browser process using Penthouse + Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, google-cloud-run

I'm ocassionally getting this error when using [Penthouse](https://github.com/pocketjoso/penthouse) with [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run):

```
[1031/055417.851741:ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(201)] Could not bind NETLINK socket: Permission denied (13) 
[1031/055417.854819:ERROR:file_path_watcher_linux.cc(71)] Failed to read /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches 
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../elf/dl-tls.c: 481: _dl_allocate_tls_init: Assertion `listp->slotinfo[cnt].gen <= GL(dl_tls_generation)' failed! 
  
   
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
```

Unfortunately, this happens randomly after some time. When I redeploy it works, but again after some time, it will show the same error for all subsequent requests.

Since it's happening randomly, I can't figure a way to reproduce the issue.

Here is the code:

```js
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const browserPromise = puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
      '--window-size=1920,1200',
    ],
    defaultViewport: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1200,
    },
  });

  const critical_css = await penthouse({
    url: req.body.url,
    cssString: req.body.css,
    pageLoadSkipTimeout: 1000,
    timeout: 30000,
    puppeteer: {
      getBrowser: () => browserPromise,
    },
  });

  res.send(critical_css);
};
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/node
FROM node:12-slim

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied.
# Copying this separately prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN npm ci --only=production

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I tried increasing resources to 2 vCPUs and 4GB memory. That didn't help.

Similar issues:

- https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4164
- [Chromium inside docker image on Google Cloud Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861081/chromium-inside-docker-image-on-google-cloud-run)

Comment: File this issue here as well: https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5447537

Comment: @Pentium10 done - https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/172046972